# Can you have different API endpoints with the same static path?

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee

I am quite new to web services and java EE I was wondering if you could have different API endpoints that have the same static path?

example:

```
@Path("/onePath")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface OnePathApi {

@GET
....

@POST
...

@PUT
...

@DELETE
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can have different methods to handle the different HTTP request methods for the same URL path.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for that quick response :) I am a little bit confused of how you can POST and PUT to a static path. I thought that you needed params in your path to know what to POST and PUT. Am I missing on something?

Comment: That seems to be up to your application. If the resource you want to refer to can be identified by just "onePath" then you do not need any more parameters. If it cannot, then you need some parameters.